# How to select random cell avoiding blank cells?

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I need to select random cells in Excel inside a column while avoiding blank cells.

I don't know how to do this, looked at the help topics but could not find anything. The range is between A1 & A160

Comment: You are referring to EXCEL, am i right? If so, please tag it below.

Comment: yes i am referring to excel. how do i tag it below?

Comment: I edited anyway. As for your question, have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245028/random-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-excel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random cell in a range of cells - Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245028/random-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-excel)

Answer (score 1):

In ColumnB and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",RAND())
```

sort A:B on ColumnB and select as many from ColumnA as suits.